# JavaScript: What is the sum of two numbers in javascript?

Tags: javascript, numbers, integer, biginteger

Stuck with one problem

Does anyone have any idea why it getting such results?

```js
let x = 4153000000000000000 + 99
console.log(x) // 4153000000000000000

let y = 4153000000000000000 + 990
console.log(y) // 4153000000000001000

let z = 4153000000000000000 + 9900
console.log(z) // 4153000000000009700
```

Comment: `console.log(Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER)` JavaScript numbers cannot represent values that large.

Comment: Okay, but why it represent +990 or +9900 and why not +99 ?

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen if so then it should get same results for all

Comment: No, because JavaScript numbers are a floating point type. The way they're stored makes it so that *all* integers up to `MAX_SAFE_INTEGER` can be represented, but *some* integers beyond that range can also be represented.

Answer (score 3):

So your problem is that the numbers you have used are larger than the maximum capacity of Integer which is 9007199254740991. Thus anything larger than 9007199254740991 will cause abnormal behaviour.

Use something like :

```js
let x = BigInt("4153000000000000000")

let y = BigInt("1235")

let z = x + y;

document.write(z);
console.log(z)
```

Answer (score 2):

It is because of IEEE. Numbers above 2^53 need to be done with big Int.

The safest max number is

```
let a = Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER;
//console.log(9007199254740991);
```

and minimum number is

```
 let b = Number.MIN_SAFE_INTEGER;
 //console.log(-9007199254740991);
```

To solve this issue, we use BigInt;

```
let sum = 4153000000000000000n + 99n;
console.log(sum); // 4153000000000000099n
```

You can click [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/MAX_SAFE_INTEGER) for more details. // MDN

More reference [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/307179/what-is-javascripts-highest-integer-value-that-a-number-can-go-to-without-losin) //Stackoverflow

Comment: It's not "JavaScript numbers", its IEEE 754 numbers as implemented by the vast majority of modern computing platforms. You see exactly the same effects in most other programming languages.

Answer (score 0):

The result of your operation goes beyond the bounds of what can safely be represented by the JavaScript number type:

```js
console.log(Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER); // 9007199254740991
```

If you want to deal with larger numbers, you can use the built-in [`BigInt`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/BigInt) type:

```js
const z = 4153000000000000000n + 9900n;
console.log(`Result: ${z}`); // 4153000000000009900
```